# Firebase .Set() function only sending after refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, electron

I am trying to make a new document and set the data with it using the .set() function. This seems to be working, but it is very unpredictable. I need to refresh the page to get an update on the console. I am using these statements to initialize and send the data:

```
var firebaseConfig = {...};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebase.firestore();
const menu = db.collection(host_name);

async function addToDatabase(){
    ...
    console.log(name, price, desc, tag, available);
    var data = {
      price: price,
      description: desc,
      tag: tag,
      availability: available
    };

    const res = await menu.doc(name).set(data).then(() => {
      console.log("done");
    });
    console.log(res);
    closeMenu();
}
```

I am using node.js and electronJS. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

UPDATE: I let it try and send the request for a long time and I got a warning:
`@firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.24.0): Connection GRPC stream error. Code: 14 Message: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established`.

What causes this, and how do I go about fixing it?

Comment: If you use `await`, you shouldn't use `.then`. Remove the `.then` part, i.e.- `const res = await menu.doc(name).set(data);`

Comment: I just made that change and a similar issue persists. I do not get any errors, but the function does not work. I now have the line ```const res = await menu.doc(name).set(data);``` What would be a good way to debug this?

Comment: Another thing to note is that it is added to the document, however only after I refresh my electron app.

Comment: To start troubleshooting, are you following a documented project? Can you provide a link?